# Chatam Sofer on tumat met

Tags: sources-mekorot, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, responsa

[This article](https://www.medethics.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/306-307%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA.htm) states that the Chatam Sofer described tumat met as being not a solid fact of the layout of the building, but more something that we should view like a "viscous vapour" (קיטור צמיג) in responsum [Yoreh Deah 340](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.340?lang=bi). But I can't find this stated in the responsum; certainly not the exact words, nor from my imperfect scan anything to that effect. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: It only described the ch"s words as such , not that he said so explicitly

Comment: "This article states"... does it really? This line seems to say the opposite of what you claim: לכן נראה שלכל הדעות לא מדובר בזרימה חופשית של משהו "מעין קיטור צמיג"  - "and so it would appear that according to *all* opinions we are not speaking of a free flowing substance akin to something like a viscous vapor"... the author seems to exclude R. Sofer from the view you attribute to him. In fact he explicitly states: "אלא גם לדעת החת"ס הטומאה עוברת רק תחת גג משותף" - "even according to the view of the Hatham Sofer, the impurity only passes beneath a shared/conjoined roof" i.e. not like a vapor.

Answer (score 1):

The entire teshuvah conveys the Chasam Sofer's attitude to this question. The authors of the aforementioned article distinguish between two views of tumas ohel: either the tumah transfers within an ohel because that is what the Torah says, but it doesn't travel as, say, a viscous vapor from one ohel to the next (this is what they call the "formal ohel" view); or tumah does travel like a vapor, even from one ohel to the next if the halachic criteria (of a space of one tefach by one tefach) are met. The Chasam Sofer adopts the latter view:

> טומאה הנמשכת ממקום למקום ע"י חור טפח לא עלה על דעת שום קדמון בעולם
> שיהיה רק דרבנן כי הלכה למשה מסיני הוא שיהיה חור טפח לענין טומאה כמו ג'
> על ג' בכל התורה דלא נימא ביה לבוד וכ"כ הריטב"א בסוכה י"ח ע"א דהל"מ היא
> וכ"כ בכתו' רפ"ב וכ"כ בתשו' מהרי"ט סי' צ"ו ע"ש וכ"כ שבות יעקב ח"א סי'
> פ"ה **מה לי אהל זה או אהל אחר** וכ"כ בתשו' שער אפרים ס"סי צ"ג שתמה על
> עמיתו הש"כ שכ' סי' שע"ב נגד זה