# Tumat met on the London Underground

Tags: halacha, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, contemporary-halacha, tractate-ahilot

Apparently part of London's subway network causes problems for kohanim because it is underneath a museum that includes human remains:

> Due to the Science Museum and the Underground entrance sharing the
> same roof, at present, Kohanim are unable to
> use South Kensington station and any underground line that passes
> through it.

There is, therefore, currently a proposal to build an extra structure outside the entrance to the station: you can see before-and-after pictures [here](https://www.jewishnews.co.uk/tube-station-entrance-could-be-redesigned-to-accommodate-religious-kohanim/). I've found an explanation which says:

> The proposed structure would be set to left and right of the entrance
> to the subway, with a partial horizontal return above set just under
> the heavy existing cornice and forming a small roof structure. It is
> understood that the intention is symbolically to sever the entrance to
> the station from the building above, which houses human remains. This
> would allow access to the station to Kohanim. To be effective in this
> regard it has to extend beyond the outermost line of the cornice to
> the roof above, and so projects out from the entrance frontage beyond
> the elevation of the porch structure which it adjoins, although only
> on the right hand side.

My question is: how does this 'work' halachically? Looking at the pictures, I can't understand how the partial archway (covering only half of the entrance, ie the right-hand side) would suffice to prevent tumat met from flowing into the subway network. Can anyone figure it out?

Comment: "tumat met... _flowing_ into the subway network". Does it flow? Why did you choose that word? EDIT: I just saw your [other question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/chatam-sofer-on-tumat-met), fair enough

Comment: @RabbiKaii Seems like a perfectly apt word. Eg Mishnah Ohalot 14:2 talks about tumah travelling through gaps and openings of certain sizes. What word would you use?

Comment: It's an innocent question from someone not baki. I see the word **מֵבִיא** אֶת הַטֻּמְאָה
, and can see how that might fit with flow, but not necessarily. Your other question seems to suggest a good reason to think this way and I am curious to see where these questions go

Comment: There is not enough detail provided of the layout of the specific station for us to answer how it works.

Comment: @DoubleAA Probably not necessary to comment if all you have to say is that you don't know?

Comment: @Zarka indeed and that isn't all I said. You asked Can anyone figure it out? and I'm telling you that based on what's provided the answer is no. Maybe you'll get lucky and someone here will volunteer to go to the station or talk to the organizers and get more info for you.

Comment: @DoubleAA I’m not sure you can speak on behalf of ‘everyone’. Somebody might well be able to explain how an arch that covers only half of a doorway can shield tumah.

Comment: [Another example of this novel principle is that someone carrying human remains into an airport terminal or medical facility that connects to a subway station conveys tumah throughout the entire subway system and prohibits any kohen from remaining anywhere in the subway, since the entire system qualifies as one large ohel. Therefore someone dying in a Bronx subway station contaminates a kohen awaiting his commuter train in Penn Station!](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/12074)

Comment: @Shmuel Absolutely. That’s why I’m wondering how the archway helps.

Comment: Interesting. I saw recent articles saying that the local government is adjusting the subway station on religious grounds.

Comment: I'm just trying to help so you don't sit around much waiting. You may obviously do as you please. Good luck!

Comment: I could not find a source for the phrase quoted in the question: "and any underground line that passes through it". Maybe it's paywalled or not indexed. Dear @Zarka: Could you please briefly try to dig through your browser history?

Comment: @Unforgettableidsupportsmonica It’s in the planning application which, unfortunately, can’t be linked to (I tried!) because it’s in some annoying database format.

Comment: @DoubleAA Someone who isn’t you has provided a helpful answer below so I wasn’t waiting in vain.

Comment: Saw in the newspaper (I bought it just to see if it said) quotes the UOHC: "the whole Underground line that runs past or connects to that entrance is prohibited for [Cohanim] to use. By providing an outside archway it breaks up the one-roof phenomenon."

Comment: "I've found an explanation which says" where did you find this?

Comment: @Deuteronomy As I said immediately above: "It’s in the planning application which, unfortunately, can’t be linked to (I tried!) because it’s in some annoying database format."

Comment: @Zarka please link the database and detail what you clicked on or key words searched to find the document. Thank you

Comment: It’s the Kensington Council planning portal and you search for planning applications on Exhibition Road.

Comment: I have emailed the UOHC asking for the halachos and they have referred me to Vaad Mishmeres Hakohanim Tel; 03330150771. If you live in england you can call them to ask. If you increase the bounty to 200, I'll do so for you :)

Comment: @Zarka: There are two cases: [LB/22/07522](https://www.rbkc.gov.uk/LB/22/07522) and [PP/22/06014](https://www.rbkc.gov.uk/PP/22/06014). If you scroll to the "Documents" section at the bottom of each case, you can discover that it has ten or more attached documents. ❧ Where should we look, please? It would be good if you could please [edit] your original post and tell us. ❧ Even if you can't find a way to link to a document, please at least tell us the title, author, date, and any other metadata which you think is important.

Comment: This is a *chumra*. https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=54019

Comment: https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/kohanim-london-tube-underground-science-museum-b2454227.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that tumah is being transferred via the grey ledge. Perhaps that ledge extends to entrance to the museum both to the right and to the left.

If that is the case tumah would spread from the entrance of the museum to the area under the ledge (if there is a tefach width). From there it would spread to the entrance to the subway.

The proposed black structure would stop the tumah from spreading to the entrance of the subway.

It takes a bit more guesswork to figure out why the black structure needs to extend over the entrance. Perhaps there is something above the entrance, some kind of structure jutting out from the building above. The black structure could be extending beyond the reach of the upper structure and blocking the tuma

So this would be one scenario which would explain how it would suffice.

Comment: That’s really helpful - it hadn’t occurred to me that the vertical parts of the archway might be the key. 
When you say ‘some kind of structure jutting out from the building above’, presumably you mean that it only juts out above where the horizontal part of the black archway is?

Comment: @Zarka correct. I still feel something is missing...